# Extend existing table or design a new one?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a database with a table which named **Category**, different category contains different articles, but as time goes by, only **Category** is not enough for distinguish articles on website, so... to meets our demands, we prepare to create new tables.

our category table like this:

```
Category
-------------
id
name
description
image
```

we want to create new table(**more than one**) like this:

```
Topic
--------------
id
name
description
image
icon(.svg)
display(boolean)
```

new tables are just like `Category` table, but add more one or two column.

In this situation, what choice is better for **Content Management** and **server**/**AWS-RDS** query efficacy? (or can't get both?)

1. create new table
2. add a column which like `Class(class1 = category, class2 = topic, class3 =...)` to redefine existing content?

or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense to create a new table because these are 2 separate concepts in your domain logic. Also, it is better for query performance and you get more flexibility because, if you need to, you can easily add columns to each table independently.